# How do I find Bran in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Bran is one of the huskies you get in the Dawnguard DLC. I cannot find him at all. I've tried fast travel, reloads, and I even recruited the other husky as a replacement. But that one died. Bran couldn't die unless I killed him myself and I'm very frustrated. I've gone back and ran through so many Nordic ruins and quest lines. He just isn't there. Is there something I can do to fix this? This is on Xbox 360.

Comment: There is one bug on [the wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bran) for 360 that says if he is left alone for too long, he may sink through the roof of Fort Dawnguard.  If that happened, you'll likely have to reload a save that was before this happened.